# Recursive Functions

Tags: c#, recursion

I want to get any non empty value from my string array (starting from reverse). I want to use recursive function for achieving my goal. Below is sample of code I have written.

```
protected string getInvNo(string[] arg, int lengthV)
{
    if (arg[lengthV] != "")
        return arg[lengthV];
    else if (lengthV >= 0)
        getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1);
    else
        return "";
}
```

It's showing error not all path return value. Requested to help me what's I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: change `getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1);` to `return getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1);`

Comment: int cnt = 0;
    protected string getInvNo(string[] arg, int lengthV)
    {
        cnt = ++cnt;

        if (cnt > 10)
        {
            return "";
        }

        if (arg[lengthV] != "")
        {
            return arg[lengthV];
        }
        else if (lengthV >= 0)
        {
            return getInvNo(arg, lengthV - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

Comment: Please avoid adding the solution to the question's body. Instead, either delete your post or answer your own question and accept if so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question. If it's radically different to any of the existing answers post it as an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a bit redesign your code:

1. You've omitted `return` in the `getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1);`
2. What if array's item is `null`? If we have to skip it as well as empty `""` one, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is the choice
3. Add validation (since method is `protected` one I can inherit your class and call the method with *any* arguments I like)
4. Change method into `static`

Implementation:

```
// static: you don't use "this" in the context, and the method is not a virtual one
protected static string getInvNo(string[] arg, int index)
{
    // Validation
    if (null == arg)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
    else if (index >= arg.Length)
      index = arg.Length - 1; // or throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index"); 

    // Stop conditions:
    if (index < 0)                               // 1. Array exhausted
        return ""; 
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg[index]))  // 2. We've found non-empty value
        return arg[index];

    return getInvNo(arg, index - 1);
}
```

Please, notice that usually we solve such problems without recoursion:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string result = arg.LastOrDefault(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) ?? "";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`lengthV > 0` will fix the index going out of range to -1.

```
static string getInvNo(string[] arg, int lengthV)
{
    if (arg[lengthV] != "")
    {
        return arg[lengthV];
    }

    return lengthV > 0 ? getInvNo(arg, lengthV - 1) : "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Return here:

```
if (arg[lengthV] != "")
       return arg[lengthV];
else if (lengthV >= 0)
      getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1);
      return "this is your missing return value";
else
      return "";
```

Comment: Hi, I have doubt about working of this code. Is it length will be decrease constantly till 0?  or it will get stuck till length - 1 ?

Comment: I am answering your problem "It's showing error not all path return value. Requested to help me what's I am missing"

Comment: I don't know what is the result of this function else if (lengthV >= 0)
      getInvNo(arg, lengthV-1); the important is you have to return a string value on that part.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but it is wrong. It will not return the value from the array if the last item of the array is an empty string, but return the hard coded string.

Comment: Yeah comment appreciated.. @Toshi but i'm just answering what the question is.. and i don't know the result of his function ideally.. only he is the one who knows it..

Comment: I'm just telling where is your problem error... and told you that you must put a return value on that part. It's a common sense man.. But any way thanks